# how to send a file to google drive with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, google-drive-api, qt5

Hi I'm a begging programmer. I've created an app in QT but stumbled upon file sync to google drive ( which my app is supposed to do ). I've followed the article on how to authenticate to google api from [here](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/01/25/connecting-qt-application-google-services-using-oauth-2-0/):

and managed to make it working right.

Here's the code that works:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow>
#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <QObject>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler>
#include <QJsonArray>

void FileIO::sendToDrive(){

     auto google = new QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow;
     google->setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
     QObject::connect(google, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::authorizeWithBrowser,
        &QDesktopServices::openUrl);


    QFile jsonFile("E:/Documents/QTProjects/swwe/autho.json");
    jsonFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QJsonDocument document;
    document = QJsonDocument().fromJson(jsonFile.readAll());


    const auto object = document.object();
    const auto settingsObject = object["web"].toObject();
    const QUrl authUri(settingsObject["auth_uri"].toString());
    const auto clientId = settingsObject["client_id"].toString();
    const QUrl tokenUri(settingsObject["token_uri"].toString());
    const auto clientSecret(settingsObject["client_secret"].toString());
    const auto redirectUris = settingsObject["redirect_uris"].toArray();
    const QUrl redirectUri(redirectUris[0].toString()); // Get the first URI
    const auto port = static_cast<quint16>(redirectUri.port()); // Get the port



    google->setAuthorizationUrl(authUri);
    google->setClientIdentifier(clientId);
    google->setAccessTokenUrl(tokenUri);
    google->setClientIdentifierSharedKey(clientSecret);

    auto replyHandler = new QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler(port);
    google->setReplyHandler(replyHandler);

    google->grant();

    auto reply = google->get(QUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me"));

 }
```

to authenticate the app correctly. Then I don't know how to send a single text file to google drive. I've seen examples from google documentation but I have no idea how to put them in a context of my code.

Can any one give me an example how to send a single text file in this context?

Cheers.
Duo

Comment: Please make the title of your question more meaningful.

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: Is `void FileIO::sendToDrive()` a typo for `int main()`?

Comment: No, this is a begging of  FileIO.cpp file and a definition of sendToDrive() method. (if I understood your question)